# RoR character class regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, cjk

I have the following line of code in my Ruby on Rails app, which checks whether the given string contains Korean characters or not:

```
isKorean = !/\p{Hangul}/.match(word).nil?
```

It works perfectly in the console, but raises a syntax error for the actual app:

```
invalid character property name {Hangul}: /\p{Hangul}/
```

What am I missing and how can I get it to work?

Comment: What is the result of `"#{RUBY_VERSION}-p#{RUBY_PATCHLEVEL}"` in the console and in the app?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a character encoding issue, you need to add:

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

to the top of the Ruby file you're using that regex in. You can probably use any encoding that the character class you're using exists in instead of UTF-8 if you wish. Note that in Ruby 2.0, UTF-8 is now the default, so this is not needed in Ruby 2.0+.

This is known as a "magic comment". You can and should read more about [encoding in Ruby 1.9](http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/ruby_19s_three_default_encodings). Note that encoding in Rails views is handled automatically by `config.encoding` (set to UTF-8 by default in `config/application.rb`.

It was likely working in the console because your terminal is set to use UTF-8 already.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Having set the default encoding to UTF-8 in `application.rb`, I was expecting it to work throughout the app. Turns out, I was wrong.

Comment: @ArnoldSakhnov Yea that setting only applies to views (presumably because Rails can set the encoding when it renders the view, but Ruby is the one loading class files, etc.).